# VBA - weird problem with control font on UserForm

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a VBA `UserForm` (in a Word document), that has some `CheckBox` controls inside a `Frame` control.

All of my CheckBox controls are set to use the Tahoma font (the default for controls), but one of them is showing as Verdana. That is, it says Tahoma in the properties dialog, but the font actually used to display the text is Verdana (both at design time and at run time).

[Now, I should mention that I did mess around with the fonts for a while, and Verdana was one of the fonts I used at one point, but now I've set everything back to Tahoma.]

You're probably thinking - just delete and re-create the CheckBox. Tried that. I also tried copying one of the CheckBoxes that displays correctly. No joy.

Here's the really **crazy** thing: the CheckBox (or any other CheckBox I create) only shows as Verdana if it's at a particular position on the form. If I move it up or down a couple of notches, it's fine. *Any* CheckBox I move into this particular position magically shows as Verdana until I move it somewhere else. Unfortunately, I need it to be in that position (and not be Verdana)!

I've battled with this for hours, and tried exporting and re-importing the code, saving as a Word 2007 document (I was originally using 2003), everything I can think of short of re-creating the form from scratch (which I don't want to do, as it's huge).

I presume that there's some sort of corruption of the form, but the saved .frx file is in a binary format, so I can't check (or edit) it.

Anyone seen this problem? Any solutions out there?

**EDIT**: I said above that the problem CheckBox shows as Verdana. That's not correct. I've established by trial-and-error that it's actually **Tahoma** - but at **9pt** instead of 8pt. Everything else above still holds, but the problem is with the size of the text, not the font face.

Comment: Give the new checkbox a different name (other than the old name) & see if that helps.

Comment: @shahkalpesh: it's not the name, because as I mentioned, I can copy an existing checkbox, or create a new one, and the problem occurs with those too (if I move them into the 'bermuda triangle').

Comment: What is the font size on the user form itself?  Perhaps there is an angle there.

Comment: @mikemay: actually, there's a whole slew of "parent" objects, since the CheckBox in question is inside a Page of a Multipage, which is in a Frame. You may be right that it's inheriting something, and I did try mucking about with the other controls (and re-creating stuff from scratch, etc.), but it's **such** a bizarre bug that I've given up trying to find any actual logic to it. To spend any more time on it would be futile, I think, and I'll close this question and try not to let it bother me - although it'll catch my eye every time I look at that dialog! Thanks, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of my colleagues had the same problem, and discovered that if you change the size of the affected formfield (making it fractionally taller), it makes the problem go away. (Why???!)

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same when having checkboxes inside a frame. Some of the checkboxes became tiny, but not all, the ones in the top half of the frame remained unchanged.

By changing the fontsize property of the frame to a bigger fontsize, this issue magically disappeared from the checkboxes.

Answer (score 1):

The trouble with incorrectly displayed text results from the "grid". Text is only correctly displayed when the top position of a control aligns with a multiple of 6. I do use the following to avoid such problems:

```
Public Function AdjustedToVerticalGrid(ByVal atvg_si As Single, _
                          Optional ByVal atvg_threshold As Single = 1.5, _
                          Optional ByVal atvg_grid As Single = 6) As Single
' -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Returns an integer which is a multiple of the grid value (stvg_grid)
' considering a certain threshold (atvg_threshold) which defaults to 1.5. The
' result vertically aligns a control in a userform to a grid value which ensures
' that a text within the control is correctly displayed in accordance with its
' font size. A threshold (atvg_threshold) of 1.5 - the default - with a grid
' value (atvg_grid) of 6 - the default - means:
'  7.5 < si >= 0   results to 6
' 13.5 < si >= 7.5 results in 12
' -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    AdjustedToVerticalGrid = (Int((atvg_si - atvg_threshold) / atvg_grid) * atvg_grid) + atvg_grid
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the behaviour is not even related to multiples of 6 as Walter experienced, at least in my case. The Top parameter of a particular checkbox was set to 112, and the Tahoma font appeared to be 1 point larger than the font settings showed (and I changed the setting several times, often in concert with other checkboxes' settings, to make sure it was the intended 10). Changing the Top parameter to 110 caused the font to display at the correct size, but so did setting Top to 111 and 113. Apparently a Top setting of 112 is a no-bueno situation, at least in this userform. The issue has been noticeable at times, and not at others, so, this means ... ?

Coupled with some userform-self-resizing-at-runtime gremlins (drag the bottom-right corner when viewing the Object in the Editor **after** runtime and all of the controls snap back to the correct size/place, but requires resetting the userform back to the intended height/width; oh, and **don't** run the code with the Object visible in the Editor to avoid the issue altogether), the Editor's behaviour is getting a bit tiring.